# Modules, Invariant Dimension Property, Direct Sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let R be a ring with no zero divisors such that for all $r,s \in R$ there exist $a,b \in R$, not both zero, with ar + bs = 0.
> (a) If $R = K \oplus  L$ (module direct sum), then K = 0 or L = 0.
> (b) If R has an identity, then R has the invariant dimension property.

This question is from my module theory assignment and I am struck on the problem.

(a) I am completely stumped by this and I don't have any idea.

(b)  for all $r,s\in R$ there exist $a,b \in R$ , not both 0 with ar + bs = 0. Now, this is a thing I deduced: Let X be the basis. Then $X={x_1 , ... ,x_m}$ be the basis. Now, let m be odd , then for all {$x_1,x_2$}, {$x_3, x_4$},...{$x_{m-2} ,x_{m-1}$} there exists r and s for each couple such that $rx_{p}+ sx_{q} =0$  and $rx_{m+1}=0$. Then, $x_{m+1}$ will also be 0 as R doesn't have a zero divisor. Now, if m is even then all such elements will be made 0 by m/2 couples which means that any such set X in Linearly Independent.

So, I think 1 is the only element in the basis and any other basis must contain only 1  element and hence invariant dimension property.

Comment: If you do a) by contradiction, it solves itself. Please don't add context that is only "i have no clue."  Certainly if you've worked on it any amount of time you'd have _some_ forward progress, even if it wasn't complete or correct.

Comment: Is "invariant dimension property" the same thing as [invariant basis number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_basis_number)?

Comment: @rschwieb It means that If R has 2 different basis X and Y then they  must have same number of elements ie same cardinality.

Comment: Ok, so it is not the same. I have not actually heard that before, but it looks somewhat interesting for rings without identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) This part solves itself: suppose $k\in K$ and $\ell\in L$, both nonzero.  Then $ak+b\ell=0$ for some nonzero $a,b$.  But this says $K\cap L\neq\{0\}$.  In that case $K+L$ cannot be a direct sum.

b) You're overcomplicating this. Suppose the basis just has *more than one element*. Then your condition that $ax_1+bx_2=0$ just says that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not linearly independent over $R$, and you have a contradiction.  This was suggested by part a) because the definition of a basis requires it to separate the module into a direct sum of submodules.

Comment: This question and the term “invariant dimension property” come from Hungerford’s *Algebra*, and there the invariant dimension property means the same thing as IBN. I think OP got a bit mixed up here because this answer would be correct if the definition he gave was correct, but his definition unfortunately isn’t correct.

Comment: @PhilipSpeegle Hi.  Rereading the question now, I think the poster answered my query as if I had asked "what does it mean for $R_R$ to be IDP?" rather than what I intended "what does it mean for a module to be IDP?"  In that light, everything seems consistent, including the OP and their following comment.

Comment: If that is true then it seems the deficit is that they did not realize they needed to prove it for all f.g. free modules.

Answer (score 2):

For part (b), recall that to show $R$ has the invariant dimension property, we need to show that every basis for a free $R$-module $F$ has the same cardinality. In other words, if $R^m\cong R^n$, $m=n$.

The method you are trying to use does not quite work. Let $x_1,x_2\in F$. Since $x_1,x_2$ are not elements of $R$, we cannot assume that there exists $a,b\in R$ such that $ax_1+bx_2 = 0$, so the proof breaks down a bit.

This question has been posted a lot on this site, and I don't think I have seen the following proof for it, so I will post a way to proceed:

Suppose $F$ is a free module on $R$ such that both $F\cong R^n$ and $F\cong R^m$. This implies that $R^n\cong R^m$. Without loss of generality, suppose $m>n$. By taking the module quotient by $R^{n-1}$, we see that $R\cong R^{m-n+1}$, so $R\cong R\oplus R^{m-n}$ as an $R$-module. By part (a), either $R=0$ or $R^{m-n} = 0$, a contradiction. This implies that $m=n$, so $R$ has the invariant dimension property.

Comment: *By taking the module quotient by $^{−1}$, we see that $≅^{−+1}$*. Unfortunately, I think this does not follow. What assurance do we have that the rank of the quotient of $R^m$ by a free submodule of rank $n-1$ is $m-n+1$? After all, we don't even know ahead of time that the rank is defined and behaves like that.   At least one would have to give a different reasoning for this "cancellation."

Comment: Indeed, [there exists an example of a domain without IBN](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/79/) and it would fail that step of the  argument. Of course, it is not a counterexample to the OP because part a) excludes all but right Ore domains (and the example I linked is not right ore.)